# Pipeline Jenkins: run cp source destination command using sh in groovy with source and destination declared in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run the following in groovy:

```
def source="path_to_source"
def destination="path_to_destination"
sh 'scp -r ${source} ${destination}'
```

But in `sh`, groovy does not replace the `source` and `destination` values and it comes out as blank. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes instead to allow string interpolation:

```
sh "scp -r ${source} ${destination}"
```

Comment: Good to hear. Please use the checkmark on the left to mark this as solved.